# TensorflowInferenceInterface result has different shape then expected

Tags: android, tensorflow

I have a simple multilayer perceptron model that was built on Python and store as protobuff which contains three layers:

**h_1**(shape=[216,256])->**h_2**(shape=[256,256])->**h_out**(shape=[256,3])

I used [TensorFlowInferenceInterface](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/android/java/org/tensorflow/contrib/android/TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java) to load it and print out operations: which seems correct

h_out: Const 'h_out:0' shape=[256, 3] dtype=FLOAT

h_2:  Const 'h_2:0' shape=[256, 256] dtype=FLOAT

h_1:  Const 'h_1:0' shape=[216, 256] dtype=FLOAT

However, when I try to feed/run/fetch it like this

```
inferenceInterface.feed("h_1:0", input, 216, 1);
inferenceInterface.run(new String[]{"h_out"});
inferenceInterface.fetch("h_out:0", **RESULT**);
```

The result was a float array with length 768, instead of 3 which I was hoping to get from.

Please let me know if I did anything incorrectly.

Thanks.

Comment: You should look at the code on how h_out is defined...according to the numbers you get it seems h_out is flattened,if you want to have the saame shape you need to do   reshape the results into 256,3(256X3=768), so if your variable returned from feed/run/fetch is results, then do results.reshape(256,3) , i am surprised accessing h_out without using h_out:0 works for you\

Comment: thank you, yes i did put h_out:0. Let me updated it. I thought after fetch I'll get the result but not the whole flatten tensor.